# How to make Jetty print logs

Tags: java, maven-2, logging, jetty, slf4j

My project runs on Wicket+Spring+JPA/Hibernate. When I run it using the command:

> `mvn jetty:run`

I'd like jetty to print logs I make in the code. I have for example the following DAO implemented:

```
@Repository(value = "isinDao")
public class IsinDaoJpa implements IsinDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IsinDaoJpa.class);

    public Isin findById(Long id) {
        return em.find(Isin.class, id);
    }

    public List findAll() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("select e from Isin e");
        logger.info("DAO: All ISINs selected");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

How do I make Jetty print this information real-time into the command line window?

In pom.xml, I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use SLF4-to-log4j bridge, you need to configure logging in log4j configuration.

To configure log4j logging with Spring you need to add the following to `web.xml` (before `ContextLoaderListener`):

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then configure log4j in `/WEB-INF/log4j.xml` (you may also use traditional `log4j.properties`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c\n\t%m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="... your package ...">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

**See also:**

- [Log4jConfigListener javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html)
- [log4j.xml syntax](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat)